# GemBox DocumentModel.Load() cannot read Pdf file

Tags: c#, gembox-document

Currently i am unable to load original pdf document using GemBox. it gives me below error in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z048C.png). and I am using Acrobat 9.

I have tried using 8/16/2018 fixes too. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Basic Code i am using is,

```
using GemBox.Document;
using System;

namespace Pdf2Text
{
   class Program
   {

      [STAThread]
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
          ComponentInfo.SetLicense("My-License");

          DocumentModel document = null;
          document = DocumentModel.Load(@"E:\data\testing\HA021.pdf");
          document.Save(@"E:\data\testing\HA021.docx");
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: What do you think the error (in your screenshot) means?

Comment: @mjwills code is added as well as posting question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19051962/34092 may be worth trying.

Comment: @mjwills i am using only GemBox and not PdfSharp this time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

In the newer versions of GemBox.Document there is another PDF reader that is intended for high-fidelity tasks, see [Convert PDF to Word](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/examples/c-sharp-convert-pdf-to-docx/308).

Here is how to use it:

```
var document = DocumentModel.Load("Sample.pdf",
    new PdfLoadOptions() { LoadType = PdfLoadType.HighFidelity });
document.Save("Sample.docx");
```

**ORIGINAL:**

The current implementation of PDF reader in GemBox.Document is still in beta and cannot handle this PDF feature, "iref streams" which are cross-reference tables stored in streams.

However, GemBox.Pdf can handle cross-reference streams so as a workaround you could do something like the following:

```
// Load PDF with GemBox.Pdf.
var pdfDocument = PdfDocument.Load("Sample.pdf");
pdfDocument.SaveOptions.CrossReferenceType = PdfCrossReferenceType.Table;

// Save PDF with GemBox.Pdf.
var pdfStream = new MemoryStream();
pdfDocument.Save(pdfStream);

// Load PDF with GemBox.Document.
var document = DocumentModel.Load(pdfStream, LoadOptions.PdfDefault);
```

Last regarding the conversion of PDF to DOCX, GemBox.Document's PDF reader is currently intended for extracting text and tables from PDF files, it's not intended for any high fidelity requirement.